# If-statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have small doubt in python.

```
x = ''
if x:
    print 'y'
```

so, it will never print as 'y'

if I do :

```
x = 0
if x:
    print 'y'
```

Then also it will do the same.

Then how can differentiate if I have '' value and 0 value If I have to consider only 0 values?

Comment: if you are evaluating against 0 then do if x == 0.

Comment: no its not only against 0. there may be some interger more values. I just want to filter '' values.

Comment: if it's not only against 0 then maybe use a switch case statement or a and if elseif else type statement where you cater for the base cases if they are only a few?

Comment: You need to be more precise. What things do you want to filter? What things do you not want to filter? How did it happen that you could get the filterable values in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the object functions `__nonzero__()` and `__len__()` will be used to evaluate the condition. [From the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html):

> `object.__nonzero__(self)`
>
> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`, or their integer equivalents 0 or 1. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__nonzero__()`, all its instances are considered true.

By overloading these you can be used to specify such behavior for custom classes as well.

As for if conditions, you can specify exactly what you want to check:

```
if x: # evaluate boolean value implicitly
  pass
if x is 0: # compare object identity, see also id() function
  pass
if x == 0: # compare the object value
  pass
```

As for your special case of implicit boolean evaluation: `int` objects are considered `True` if they are nonzero; `str` objects are considered `True` if their length is nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

In python for a condition an empty iterable (here string) evaluated to false.

If you need to check if a value is `0` explicitly you have to say `x==0`

Answer (score 2):

```
if x != '':
    print 'y'
```

Works only if x is not `''`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you actually want - the wording of your question is a little confusing - but this may be illuminating:

```
>>> test_values = [0,0.00,False,'',None, 1, 1.00, True, 'Foo']
>>> for v in test_values:
    if (not v) and (v != ''):
        print "Got a logically false value, %s, which was not the empty string ''" % v.__repr__()


Got a logically false value, 0, which was not the empty string ''
Got a logically false value, 0.0, which was not the empty string ''
Got a logically false value, False, which was not the empty string ''
Got a logically false value, None, which was not the empty string ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This didnt work for u because u didnt add where to enter the number 0 in your program
the correct code for this program is :

```
x = int(input("enter the value of x : "))
if x==0:
    print("Y")
```

OUTPUT:
enter the value of x : 0
Y